# Recursive Makefile with Shared Libs

Tags: makefile

I'm creating a Makefile for a project. I have the following structure of Makefiles:

```
./Makefile
./classification/Makefile
./misc/Makefile
./APP/Makefile
./qr/libs/Makefile
```

I'm doing a recursive `make`. In each directory, I have a Makefile which generates a Shared Library. So, in the `./classification` folder, I'm going to generate `classification.so`, and thus to the other directories. In general, they have the following structure:

```
include ../standard_defs.mk

xCFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -fPIC

SOURCES=help.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=misc.so

xxDET=detection/$(EXECUTABLE)
export xxDET;

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -shared -o $@


.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(xCFLAGS) $< -c

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

And the main Makefile (`./Makefile`) has the following structure:

```
CFLAGS=`pkg-config opencv --cflags`
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config opencv --libs`

include standard_defs.mk

SOURCES=DataFormatDetResult.cpp  InputDataFiles.cpp  InputImage.cpp \
    InputManager.cpp  main.cpp  maths.cpp  misc.cpp

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=featureExtractor

all: $(LIBS) $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    make -C misc
    make -C qr/libs
    make -C classification
    make -C APP
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) misc/misc.so qr/libs/ap.so classification/classification.so APP/app.so

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c

clean:
    make -C misc clean
    make -C qr/libs clean
    make -C APP clean
    make -C classification clean
    rm -f *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

## Errors

When I try to compile the main Makefile, I got the following linking error:

```
classification/classification.so: undefined reference to `Help::InsertHelpType(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
classification/classification.so: undefined reference to `Help::Help()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [featureExtractor] Erro 1
```

`misc.so` contains the class `Help` and it seems that `classification.so` does not find it in the final compiling. However, if I run `make -C ./classification/`, I don't get any errors.

### Question 1

How can I solve this linkage problem?

#### Failed Solutions

I've tried to link `misc.so` to `classification.so`, doing this in `./classification/Makefile`:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) ../misc/misc.so
```

But it didn't work. All I've got was a new warning

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../misc/misc.so, needed by classification/classification.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

### Question 2

Is there a better way to do create a Makefile to this project?

---

***EDIT 1:*** If I run `make -C ./classification/`, it generates `./classification/classification.so` without errors. Then, if I run `make` in `./`, I get the same error.

---

***EDIT 2:*** When I ran `nm --format sysv misc.so | grep Help`, I've got:

```
$ nm --format sysv misc.so | grep Help
HelpTypes           |0000000000205120|   D  |            OBJECT|0000000000000038|     |.data
_ZN11HelpControl9PrintHelpEv|0000000000002180|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000082e|     |.text
_ZN11HelpControlC1Ev|00000000000029b0|   T  |              FUNC|0000000000000187|     |.text
_ZN11HelpControlC2Ev|00000000000029b0|   T  |              FUNC|0000000000000187|     |.text
_ZN4Help14InsertHelpTypeESs|0000000000001ac0|   T  |              FUNC|0000000000000126|     |.text
_ZN4Help9PrintHelpEi|0000000000001bf0|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000020d|     |.text
_ZN4HelpC1Ev        |0000000000001e00|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000021a|     |.text
_ZN4HelpC2Ev        |0000000000001e00|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000021a|     |.text
_ZN4HelpD1Ev        |0000000000003090|   W  |              FUNC|000000000000039b|     |.text
_ZN4HelpD2Ev        |0000000000003090|   W  |              FUNC|000000000000039b|     |.text
_ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSs4HelpESt10_Select1stIS3_ESt4lessISsESaIS3_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS3_E|0000000000003430|   W  |              FUNC|0000000000000526|     |.text
```

Comment: Do you mean that if you `make -C ./classification` and then `make`, Make builds the executable (`featureExtractor`) without error? No complaints about undefined `Help` methods?

Comment: No, when I run `make -C ./classification` it generates  `./classification/classification.so` without errors. When I run `make` in `./`, I get the same error.

Comment: Go into `./misc` and try `nm --format sysv misc.so | grep Help` and see what you get.

Comment: I put the output in my question, in ***EDIT 2***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us enough to reproduce the error, so this may take a couple of iterations.

In `misc/`, we need a way to test the `Help` class. If you don't have one already, write some simple code to that purpose in `misc/`:

```
//test_help.cpp
#include "help.h"

int main()
{
  Help H;

  return(0);
}
```

Try it:

```
make test_help.o help.o
g++ test_help.o help.o -o test_help
./test_help
```

Then with the library:

```
make misc.so
g++ test_help.o misc.so -o test_help
./test_help
```

Then move `test_help.cpp` to the upper directory and try from there:

```
make test_help.o
g++ test_help.o misc/misc.so -o test_help
./test_help
```

Then add a rule to the main Makefile:

```
test_help: test_help.o
    make -C misc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ misc/misc.so
    ./$@
```

and try `make clean ; make test_help`.

Comment: **1)** I've tried the first test, it worked without problems.
**2)** When I run the second test, I get: `./test_help: error while loading shared libraries: misc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` 
**3)** The third test worked without any problems
**4)** The fourth test returned an error: `misc/misc.so: undefined reference to 'ReportError(char const*, ...)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [test_help] Erro 1`

Comment: Doing this test I realized that to compile `help.o` I need `./misc.o`, which contains the declaration of `ReportError(char const*, ...)`. So,  in order to do the tests, I had to add `../misc.o` to the compiling command, such as: `g++ test_help.o help.o ../misc.o -o test_help`. Notice that `misc.o` is different from `misc.so`

Comment: Thank you @Beta. using your tests I could fix the error. I just had to move `misc.{cpp,h}` to the `misc/` directory and change the `include`s  in the other source files. `misc.so` wasn't compiling correctly because these source files were missing.

The test cases you passed were very useful and I will use it when I get Makefile problems again, mainly if I'm developing one to a project that I'm not entirely familiar --- such this one.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Remember, a library implies an act of faith.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get rid of the recursive Makefiles. Although they are somewhat common, [recursive make is inherently broken](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). The main reason, that they are common is because that is what is build when you have automake and autoconf. However autoconf and automake both go to a great length to get the recursive make structure right and I have yet to seem anyone who get's a recursive make structure right without these tools.

There are only a few uses where recursive make is not inherently broken, for example in the way Cmake uses recursive makefiles. But again, these makefiles are build by automated tool, so this too is hard to get right manually.

**EDIT**: Here is a short summary of the article.

The main problem with recursive makefiles is, that it keeps make from building the full dependency graph, which it needs for building stuff in the right order. Recursive make was originally meant for cases where you would need to build multiple projects at once, without any dependencies between them. As long as there is a dependency across the recursive structure, make will make it very hard to fix the order. In the best case one then is left with a system which can be build, but which break when one tries to rebuild it after editing some of the files. I've seen a lot of cases, where recursive make messed up, so that one part of the application was linked against the libraries compiled from sources before the edit, and another part was linked against libraries compiled from sources after the edit. This leads to sudden breakage of the application, which will miraculously appear after a `make clean && make`.

In other cases recursive make can mess up the build altogether. This is the case, when the targets are executed in the absolutely wrong order to begin with. This means an ordinary build is not possible. Your example seems like one of those cases. Although I haven't looked at it too closely, it seems that make is not building all needed libraries correctly, because it does not fully know the dependencies.

In almost all cases a parallel make is completely rendered impossible when a recursive make is used. At least I have yet to see a manual recursive make structure which can reliably used with a `make -j X`.

There are two solutions:

- Have the makefiles constructed by one of the tools, such as autotools or cmake. However this requires learning one more tool. Also the usability of these tools is highly debated (at least for autotools).
- Get rid of the recursive structure by providing one makefile from which make can derive the full dependency graph. I've seen some people do this actually in a single file even with multiple libraries and automatic source detection, but I wouldn't so I cannot recommend that. Better yet is to have multiple files, one for each subdirectory and then use `include` to combine them into a large file at the root of the directory tree. This way make can only be called at the root of the tree, but it will always know the full set of dependencies. This way is also recommended by the article.

Comment: Do you suggest me to use one of these tools? Which one: `autoconf`, `automake`, or `cmake`?

Comment: Uhm no, not necessarily. I think autotools (i.e. autoconf and automake) are a good way to get a project configured under several different different systems with a different set of libraries installed in different paths. Cmake is similar, but attempts to also be multi-platform. These tools are however a total overkill if the system configuration is well known of few other dependencies are needed. In that case hand-written makefiles are the best way to go. There are some ideas in the article I linked, but I'll summarize the main points again in an edit.

Comment: Next time I won't use recursive Makefiles. If I need to do a Makefile to a small project, I will research how to use those `include` to create a single Makefile; if it is a bigger project, I will use `cmake` or `autotools`. 

For the project of this question, in particular, the best solution is to use `cmake`, because it will be compiled in different computers and configurations. Thank you!